# firebase import json issue

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i'm trying to import a JSON.data from another application in my firebase database in order to change some values without write the whole thing.
I think the procedure was successful.
[Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qngbh.png)

But when i go in my app's js and change the original link with my current firebase link nothing happens. The original link from the original database works. What i am doing wrong? The line i am using is `var firebase = new Firebase('https://project-5869528515490217304.firebaseio.com/events');`
Just changed the url with my project's url.

Comment: Well i'm using this. The photo with the structure is from the new SDK.

Comment: But your code `var firebase = new Firebase('XXXX');` seem like the old one ?

Comment: So how i can call my database with the new SDK? i thought the call will be the same.

Comment: Can you share the minimal code+JSON (as text, no screenshot please) that reproduces the problem you're having? Without that, we'll just be speculating and that's not a very efficient way of helping. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

New project cannot use old SDK to access data.

Follow the document: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web

It wont be so pain. :)

Comment: This is not completely true. Code written using the 2.x SDK can access a *database* created in the new console without problems. But if the code uses *authentication*, it will indeed not work against a project *created* in the new console.